# Фон шапки сайта не закрашивается. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: css, css3, html5, background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>
    <head>
        <title>GGGG</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel = "style" href = "SITE\ProjectCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <P><header>
             <li><a href = '#'>GGG</a></li>
             <li><a href = '#'>GG</a></li>
             <li><a href = '#'>G</a></li>
        </header></P>
        <h1>Приветствуем на сайте</h1>
        <h1>GGGG</h1>
    <noscript>Для работы сайта включите JavaScript.</noscript>
    <!-- Подключение JavaScript-->
    <script src="ProgectJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
p{
    background-color: #67E300!important;
}
h1{
    font-family: Arial;
font-size: 20 px;}
```

Comment: У вас в разметке тег <p> написан как <P> и стили надо обернуть в тег  <style>

Answer (score 0):

1. Оберните ваш CSS код в `<style>css код</style>` и вставьте его в `<head>...</head>`.
2. У вас не корректное использование `html` тегов. Тег `p` по уровню использования является "строковым" тегом и предназначен по большей степени для стилизации текстов/контента, а не блоков (header, aside и тд.) и div-ов - как вы пытаетесь его применить, по этому у вас и не работает.

Прикрепляю корректный вариант:

**P.S.** если хотите обернуть тег `header` используйте `div` с классом.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>
<head>
    <title>GGGG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="style" href="SITE\ProjectCSS.css">
    <style>
        header {
            background-color: #67E300 !important;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <li><a href='#'>GGG</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>GG</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>G</a></li>
</header>
<h1>Приветствуем на сайте</h1>
<h1>GGGG</h1>
<noscript>Для работы сайта включите JavaScript.</noscript>
<!-- Подключение JavaScript-->
<script src="/ProgectJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за поянения, вы где-нибудь учились или вы самоучка?

Comment: И вопрос <head> разве не для внешних факторов сайта( иконка сайта, название сайта и т.д.)?

Comment: Самоучка, как и 99% я думаю. 

CSS можно использовать внутри <head> или <body>, но лучше всего в <head> т.к. стили буду применятся быстрее. 

В целом, в идеальном случае, нужно выносить весь CSS код в отдельный файл (так как у вас JS организован) и подключать в <head>.